# How to update a Python dictionary with a reference dictionary the Pythonic way?

Tags: dictionary, python

I think it is pretty straightforward. All I am trying to do is update the original dictionary's `'code'` with that of another dictionary which has the value. I get a feeling 2 for loops and an IF loop can be further shortened to get the answer. In my actual problem, I have few 1000's of dicts that I have to update. Thanks guys!

**Python:**

```
referencedict = {'A': 'abc', 'B': 'xyz'}

mylistofdict = [{'name': 'John', 'code': 'A', 'age': 28}, {'name': 'Mary', 'code': 'B', 'age': 32}, {'name': 'Joe', 'code': 'A', 'age': 43}]

for eachdict in mylistofdict:
    for key, value in eachdict.items():
        if key == 'code':
            eachdict[key] = referencedict[value]

print mylistofdict
```

**Output:**

```
[{'age': 28, 'code': 'abc', 'name': 'John'}, {'age': 32, 'code': 'xyz', 'name': 'Mary'}, {'age': 43, 'code': 'abc', 'name': 'Joe'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to loop over all values of `eachdict`, just look up `code` directly:

```
for eachdict in mylistofdict:
    if 'code' not in eachdict:
        continue
    eachdict['code'] = referencedict[eachdict['code']]
```

You can probably omit the test for `code` being present, your example list always contains a `code` entry, but I thought it better to be safe. Looking up the code in the referencedict structure assumes that all possible codes are available.

I used `if 'code' not in eachdict: continue` here; the opposite is just as valid (`if 'code' in eachdict`), but this way you can more easily remove the line if you do not need it, and you save yourself an indent level.

Comment: if 'code' in eachdict: eachdict['code'] = referencedict[eachdict['code']]

Comment: @ralu: that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Eric: until you work with several conditions, when you do. Many a python code goes into too many indent level just because they don't know how to do `continue`.

Comment: Thank you. This works. I will do a timeit on both approaches just for the heck of it but I feel this will be quicker.

Comment: @ThinkCode: without the `if` statement they'll likely be as fast as each other. Choose what you find most readable and maintainable instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
referencedict = {'A': 'abc', 'B': 'xyz'}

mylistofdict = [{'name': 'John', 'code': 'A', 'age': 28}, {'name': 'Mary', 'code': 'B', 'age': 32}, {'name': 'Joe', 'code': 'A', 'age': 43}]

for x in mylistofdict:
   try: 
    x['code']=referencedict.get(x['code'])
   except KeyError:
       pass
print(mylistofdict)
```